# Use of JSTL in a web app

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, jstl, jsp-tags

I am a front end or UI developer with limited understanding of Java. I have a java based web app with JSTL used in it..I would like to understand the exact use of JSTL. Is it always used within JSP pages and is it used only for getting data from the database. Could you please explain with some basic examples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it always used within JSP pages

Yes.

> ... and is it used only for getting data from the database.

No.  In fact, in most cases it is **bad practice** to access the database from a JSP, using JSTL or using other means (e.g. scriptlets).

> does it mean like most JSP would have an associated Java file like 1-1 mapped, where the logic to get data using SQL query is written and is given to the JSP page.

Sort of.  But there is not necessarily a 1 to 1 mapping:

- Not all JSPs need to access the database.
- A Java servlet may use multiple JSPs to render different output pages.
- Different servlets may share a single JSP; e.g. to render a common error message page.

> If yes, what exactly is the role of JSTL code within the JSP.

The aim of a JSP is to render output; typically HTML pages, but it could be anything text-based.  JSTL is used within JSPs when the the output rendering logic is too complicated or messy to express using JSP EL.

---

**UPDATE**

The old-fashioned alternative to JSTL and JSP EL is to embed Java code ... i.e. scriptlets ... in the JSPs.  For example:

```
<c:if test="${a == 'true'}">
    hi
</c:if>
```

is equivalent to something like this:

```
<% if ("true".equals(context.findAttribute("a")) { %>
    hi
<% } %>
```

> Also for JSTL use, from what I understand, it is used within the JSP for dynamic HTML rendering through if-else statements.

You are describing HTML whose structure and content *depends* request parameters, configuration parameters, data fetched from the database and so in.  This is the primary  uses of JSTL.

However, this is NOT what is normally referred to as "Dynamic HTML".  Dynamic HTML is where *the browser* changes the HTML of the currently displayed page, for e.g., when Javascript embedded in the page changes displayed page by modifying the DOM.

Comment: Thx a lot..I understand most of what you have said except the servlet thing which you just added...i.e. The 2nd and 3rd bullets about servlets..Also for JSTL use, from what i understand it is used within the JSP for dynamic HTML rendering through if..else statements..would it be possible for u to give any example when you say it is an alternative to scriptlets ? Thx again for the detailed help..

Comment: I aplogize for using the term Dynamic HTML..but u seem to have understodd what i meant and we are now narrowing down to the exact info which I am looking for..So essentially within the Jsp, we try to include HTML for the various scenarios and depening on certain parameters those are dynamically shown in the browser..lets say we have a <table> element to be shown, whoose data is pulled from the database..so in this case within the JSP, will it just output table html with JSTL placeholder pulling data or how will it work...

Answer (score 7):

JSP tags are used to generate HTML dynamically in a JSP, but without mixing Java code and HTML markup. The JSTL is a library of standard JSP tags. It means "JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library", and as its name indicates, it's used within JSPs.

It should never be used to get data from the database. Getting data from the database should be done before executing the JSP, in a controller written in Java. Once the controller has done its job, it should dispatch the HTTP request to a view (the JSP), whose role is to render the data.

So if your application uses `sql` tags, then it's wrong. `core` and `fmt` tags are OK. As [the Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) indicates :

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing
>   databases listed in Table 7-7 are
>   designed for quick prototyping and
>   simple applications. For production
>   applications, database operations are
>   normally encapsulated in JavaBeans
>   components.

Comment: Thx a lot for the simple explanation..so when u say controller writen in Java, does it mean like most JSP would have an associated Java file like 1-1 mapped, where the logic to get data using SQL query is written and is given to the JSP page..if yes, what exactly is the role of JSTL code  within the JSP..does it only help in HTML rendering..if possible an example would be great..

Comment: To complete Stephen's answer: read http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/web-tier/web-tier5.html for explanations about the MVC pattern in web apps. Several frameworks have their own implementation of this pattern: Stripes, Spring MVC, Struts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

JSTL - JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library - was designed to overcome a shortcoming in JSP, namely that a simpler way was needed to invoke Java libraries from the JSP page.  The previous way to do it was to escape into Java with `<%`, `%>` and `<%=` and do what you needed, which led to very complex and difficult to maintain JSP pages.

JSTL give you new tags in addition to the HTML-tags you have in your JSP-pages, but which have special meaning server side, so it is interpreted when asked for by the client, and the result put in the actual page sent back to the client.

The tag definitions can do anything you can do in Java but you should strongly consider what you do where.  Having e.g. SQL requests in your JSP-page mean that you tie business logic together with actual presentation, which has been - painfully - learned also gives complex and difficult to maintain web applications.

Comment: Thx a lot..i have very basic knowledge of Java..so wanted t,o understand what are those actual things which were previously done using scriptlets and now replaced by JSTL..like some examples if u can give...also by business logic, i think u r referring to the backend database stuff..is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

JSTL **is a "custom tag library set"** developed in and for the specifications of **the J2EE server JSP servlet engine section**. "Any tag in a Java J2EE spec. server markup page" configured for the java server written in Java2 J2EE spec **is a "Custom Tag implementation" whether JSF , JSP , JSTL or Databasing cudtom** tag. *However it is not a Java Bean (only extremely similar to them in syntax and semantic to write a class program).*
Each custom tag library has its own set of useful properties in java server markup and is why the system was developed. The Java Bean system is alike but is done through EL language.
A **"tag"** uses both a markup representation in the page and its co-bound(configured) **.class file program** in the server **to process page markup and interface or join other server processes and programs**.
*JSTL is simply java server markup library for the JSP-servelt engine as JSF is a markup for the faces-servlet engine and both are only a custom tag.*